# Generate html views of existing table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in my database that already exists medium genre, the command `rails generate model` but now I want to generate the views, its controller, helper and html, what generates when making `scaffold`, is there a command that allows me to do this?

my table:

```
class CreateTypeControlAccesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :type_control_accesses do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to use scaffold you can run the following in the terminal

`rails g scaffold [controller_name]`

Make sure that your controller name is the plural version of your model

Ex. model = user; controller/scaffold = users